# Django how to render a queryset within a list to html

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to pass multiple querysets that I can use in rendering HT

```
 context['date']=today_date
 context['doctor_list']=doctor_list
 context['appointment_list']= all_data_doctor
 context['slots'] = slots
 return(context)
```

I am able to parse all context components (date, doctor_list and slots) except appointment_list because it is a list with a queryset within it. Here is an example

```
['', '', '', '', <QuerySet [{'first_name': 'Emily', 'last_name': 'Johns'}]>, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

Here is what I am doing but does not seem to work.

```
<tbody>
{% for appt in appointment_list %}
 <tr>
  {% if appt %}
   <td>{{ appt.first_name }} {{ appt.last_name }}</td>
   {% else %}
   <td> Empty </td>
  {% endif %}
 </tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

What could be the problem? And also, is this a good way to do it? 
Thanks

Comment: How do you *construct* your `all_data_doctor`? Please do *not* try to fix this at the template level, fix it where the problem originates from.

Comment: You should definitely reorganize data you put in the context. Mixing types in list is usually a bad idea. Try to construct a query set of appointments that you will be able to iterate on.

Comment: Yes, we can fix the template, but it will typically only make matters worse. It is better to solve the problem at the right place. Here the view is doing something strange, and you should aim to fix that, not just fix the template to deal with it.

Comment: Thank you. It is much easier, now that I think clearer on it, I can easily pass a string instead of the query set, much easier to render. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A QuerySet is a collection of objects. To access its contents you have to iterate over it:

```
<tbody>
{% for appt in appointment_list %}
 <tr>
  {% if appt %}
   {% for item in appt %}
   <td>{{ item.first_name }} {{ item.last_name }}</td>
   {% endfor %}
   {% else %}
   <td> Empty </td>
  {% endif %}
 </tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

If you know that you queryset only has one entry, you can also use an index, i.e. `my_queryset[0]` in Python or `my_queryset.0` in Django templates:

```
<tbody>
{% for appt in appointment_list %}
 <tr>
  {% if appt %}
   <td>{{ appt.0.first_name }} {{ appt.0.last_name }}</td>
   {% else %}
   <td> Empty </td>
  {% endif %}
 </tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Comment: As others have commented, it might make sense to move some of that logic into your view or even better a method of a customer manager. I also agree that mixing types in lists is a bad idea, but my guess is that your list contains QuerySets or `None`, which is rendered as an empty string. I would consider that acceptable, although I would check if there isn't a way to do one query and the split up the result into your list. Maybe ask a separate question for that.

Comment: Thank you. You are right, I am just getting the full name of the person, so I can create the string and pass it in the context rather than the query set. That way all the elements in the list are strings. But good to learn how to iterate a collection of objects. Awesome!!